# Is there a technique to differentiate class behavior on generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I'd like to do something like the following, but because **T** is essentially just a *System.Object* this won't work.  I know **T** can be constrained by an interface, but that isn't an option.

```
public class Vborr<T> where T : struct
  {

    public Vborr()
    {
    public T Next()
    {
      if ( typeof( T ) == typeof( Double ) )
      {
         // do something for doubles
      }
      if ( typeof( T ) == typeof( Float ) )
      {
         // do something different for floats..
      }
    }
  }
```

I frequently find C# generics lacking.

Thanks!

Paul

Comment: Why won't it work? What are you trying to do? I'm not saying that this is a good idea, but this code should compile ok as it stands (once you fix the typos).

Comment: Where is your problem? your ifs differentiate the behavior by type, so you already found the solution. If your cast to Float... fails you could try (float)(object)x. But I'm not sure if this boxes or not.

Comment: From the 2 cases you've provided, sounds like you're looking for `where T: INumeric` or something? I wish we could have such a feature, but I don't think it's going to happen any time soon..

Comment: Ani: The Operator class in MiscUtil offers that. The performance is quite bad compared to non generic code though since it requires a lambda call on each operator.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.  In your specific example of double and float both implement IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable and IEquatable.  So if you wanted to do some object conversions for example; instead of saying if (TypeOf(T) == TypeOf(double)) you could instead say if (TypeOf(T) == TypeOf(IConvertible)) and then take advantage of the IConvertible interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole point of generics is that you can do the same thing for any valid type.

If you're truly doing something specific for the types, then the method isn't generic anymore and should be overloaded for each specific type.

```
public class Vborr<T> where T : struct
{
    public virtual T Next() { // Generic Implementation }
}

public class VborrInt : Vborr<int>
{
    public override int Next() { // Specific to int }
}

public class VborrDouble : Vborr<double>
{
    public override double Next() { // Specific to double }
}
```

Comment: One can do it as a performance optimization avoiding interface or lambda calls in certain scenarios. For example the Operator class in MiscUtil could profit from this.

Comment: Yes, good point.  But because for my users calling public T Next() the behavior is functionally the same for either Doubles or Floats.  They shouldn't have to deal w/ two classes (you can't overload on return types in C#...only in the IL is that possible)

Comment: To address your last point you could create a VborrFactory<T> class that would return the correct subclass to the user, who could view it as Vborr<T> and not care that it actually was a VborrInt, or VborrDouble or whatever.

Comment: I'm giving Justin an answer too, because it doesn't hurt to be reminded of this.  But, there are special cases where some <T> differentiation is needed as in this case where there are big performance differences between single/double - and that's the users only care.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take here would be that of a factory pattern and creating specialized instances of `Vborr` based off of the type.  For example

```
public class Vborr<T> where T : struct {
  protected Vborr() { }
  abstract T Next();
}

public static class VborrFactory { 
  private sealed class VborrFloat : Vborr<float> {
    public VborrFloat() {}
    public override float Next() {
      ...
    }
  }
  private sealed class VborrDouble : Vborr<double> {
    public VborrDobule() {}
    public override double Next() {
      ...
    }
  }
  private sealed class VborrDefault<U> : Vborr<U> {
    public VborrDefault() {}
    public override U Next() {
      ...
    }
  }
  public static Vborr<T> Create<T>() {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(double) ) { 
      return new VborrDouble();
    } else if ( typeof(T) == typeof(float) ) {
      return new VborrFloat();
    } else {
      return new VborrDefault<T>();
    }
  }
}
```